# Swift задача. Фитнес приложение

Tags: swift

Ребят очень нужна Ваша помощь, начал изучать Swift и столкнулся с нерешаемой для себя задачей. Сообщество Stackoverflow моя последняя надежда.

Условие задания:

Добавим в фитнес-трекер возможность следить за тем, чтобы пульс не выходил за заданные пределы.  Приложение должно предложить пользователю идти быстрее, чтобы увеличить пульс в случае, если его значение меньше нижнего предела, сообщить, что они двигаются в нужном темпе, если пульс в норме, либо попросить замедлиться, если пульс превысил верхний предел.

Создайте булевы константы isInTarget (внутри пределов), isBelowTarget (ниже пределов) и isAboveTarget (выше пределов), которые принимают истинные значения тогда, когда currentHR лежит в нужных пределах, становится меньше нижнего предела, либо больше верхнего предела, соответственно.  Напишите инструкцию if-else-if, которая выведет "Вы двигаетесь в правильном темпе!" в случае, если пользователь находится в нужной зоне, "Вы всё делаете правильно, но попробуйте немного ускориться!" в случае, если пульс пользователя ниже, чем нужно, и "Слишком быстро!  Замедлитесь.", если выше.

```
let targetLowerBound = 120  // нижний предел
let targetUpperBound = 150  // верхний предел
let currentHR = 147         // текущий пульс
let isInTarget = true
let isBelowTarget = true
let isAboveTarget = true
```

Как не пытался, не могу объединить Int и Bool ( 
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так!

```
let targetLowerBound = 120  // нижний предел
let targetUpperBound = 150  // верхний предел
var isInTarget = true
var isBelowTarget = true
var isAboveTarget = true

func getUserStatus(_ currentHR: Int) -> String {

    var userStatus: String = ""

    if currentHR >= targetUpperBound {
        isInTarget = false
        isBelowTarget = false
        isAboveTarget = true
        userStatus = "Слишком быстро! Замедлитесь."

    } else if currentHR <= targetLowerBound {
        isInTarget = false
        isBelowTarget = true
        isAboveTarget = false
        userStatus = "Вы всё делаете правильно, но попробуйте немного ускориться!"

    } else {
        isInTarget = true
        isBelowTarget = false
        isAboveTarget = false
        userStatus = "Вы двигаетесь в правильном темпе!"
    }

    return userStatus
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let currentHR = 147 // текущий пульс

        let textForUser = UILabel()
        textForUser.text = getUserStatus(currentHR)

    }
}
```

Необходимости в булевых я здесь конечно не вижу, но всё-таки)

Comment: большое спасибо!